# Is the ー (ちょうおん) character used with Hiragana and Kanji?

Tags: kanji, katakana, hiragana

It appears that the character is limited to Katakana. Is the character used in writing Hiragana and Kanji?

Comment: With kanji, it becomes dangerous to confuse with 一{いち}.

Comment: Placement is the key, probably why not commonly used with kanji or hiragana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that it is normally used in katakana, but it can sometimes be used in hiragana words, as a point of emphasis, to lengthen a sound more than it normally would be:

うぜー
かわいいー
なのだー

You can add it to い adjectives. Otherwise, the word in question is generally written out in hiragana rather than in kanji, but it is apparently alright to add it directly to a kanji for emphasis or silliness:

長いー
大きいー
怖いー

馬ー鹿ー！